# Combine multiple images into one image

Tags: python

I am looking for help trying to combine multiple images belonging to one user into a single image file using python script. For example,User 12568 has 7 images which i am trying to combine it into one file which will have 1-7 pages in it vertically. Same needs to be applied for over 100K + users

[image: FYI]

Comment: check opencv library

Comment: Could you please give some precision on what you mean by "single image file" ? Do you mean having all of them next to one another on a bigger image ?

Comment: i am trying to combine it vertically in a single file

Answer (score 0):

A nice way would be to use imageio.

```
import imageio
import os

path = "C:/path_to_folder/"
image_path_list = os.listdir(path)

with imageio.get_writer("new_image.tif") as new_image:
    for image_path in image_path_list:
        image = imageio.imread(path+image_path)
        new_image.append_data(image)
```

This will create a tif file with a page per image.

Note that with this code folders should only contain images.

Comment: then filter for file names you want or use `glob`